# Perl File Reading Line By Line (RegEx)

Tags: regex, perl

What I am trying to do is open a file and read it line by line.
Once I found what my regex is looking for, I want to place each one into the `@accounts` array as well as print them onto my screen.

Though I'm not getting any result. 
I must be making a simple mistake here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
my $file;
my $start;
my $end;
my @match;
my @accounts;

print "Enter the file name (example: file.txt): ";
chomp ($file = <STDIN>);


open FILE, $file or die "Cannot open $file read :$!";

while ($line=<FILE>) {

    $start = '">';
    $end = '</option>';

    @match = ($line =~ /$start(.*?)$end/g);

    foreach (@match)
    {
        push @accounts, $_;
        print " $_\n ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Don't use bareword filehandles:

```
open my $INFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";
```

2) @match??  You used the g flag, so @matches would be a better name.  Generally, array names are going to be plurals.

3) Avoid using $_ in your code:

```
for my $match (@matches) {
    print $match;
}
```

for and foreach are the same thing in perl, so use for--it's shorter to type.

4)

> $start = '">';

Are you sure you want to look for a double quote followed by a > ??  Your code works fine for me with this data file:

```
<option">hello world</option>
```

However, that is some strange looking data.

Comment: Alright thank you I will try that. The thing is I used that regex because I was not sure on how to go about with this:

The actual regex is something like option value="55">hello</option>
though the thing is with each line that 55 is a different number.how would I get the hello out of that?

Comment: Well, then post a line in your data file and describe what you want to match.

Comment: If you are trying to match the text between only option tags, you can use a regex like this: /<option .*? >(.*?)</option>/x.  But generally, there are html/xml parsers that handle all the complicated regexes and special cases for you, so you should use them, e.g. HTML::Parser.

Comment: Thank you for that. Though I still cannot get any data. 
Regex is fine, I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Okay, here is the way to ask questions: 1) This is an example of my data.  2) This is the output I want ...  3)This is what I tried ....  You posted #3, but you left out #1 and #2.

Answer (score 0):

```
use feature ":5.16";
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use strict;

my $t = "aaaa\">AAAA</option>\n bbbb\">BBBB</option> cccc\">CCCC</option>";
my $start = '">';
my $end = '</option>';
say for $t =~ /$start(.*?)$end/g;
```

Produces:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```